# Using Highmaps for Angular after the component is initialized

Tags: angular, highcharts

I'm using Highmaps with the official Angular wrapper. If I initialize the map in `ngOnInit`, it works fine (`chartMap` is set as `[options]` in the `highcharts-chart` directive):

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.chartMap = {
        chart: {
          map: mapUS
        },
    ........
    ........ 
}
```

The problem is that I don't know at the time the component starts what map I'm going to show. If I try to set it later (for example when a user clicks a button) and I don't set it in `ngOnInit`, I get an error when the component starts:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'series' of undefined
```

Is it mandatory to create the map when the component starts? Is there a way to set it later?

Comment: Please share the used code in a form of a live demo. Have you tried setting all chart options later through an update?

Comment: Just try to set the chart options after ngOnInit (for example clicking a button) and it won't work, you get the error and the div is empty. I cannot post a demo as my code is too large to extract.

Comment: Works fine for me when following the steps you have described. I have set the chart options as an empty object at first and in `ngOnInit` assigned a new object. Maybe the problem is caused by something in your code - creating a simplified example could help with finding source of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Highcharts in Angular without the wrapper